# Weird!! How to read mask info from an SWF file?

Tags: actionscript-3, mask, movieclip, starling-framework

recently i am research to build some tools like [GAF](http://gafmedia.com/converter/)

and i'm stuck by MovieClip's mask

[image: MovieClip Structure]

as the image you can see ,it's an very simple start masked by an rectangle.

i try to get those mask info from code , but got nothing. i wactch the startMc from FlashBuilder,the mask info is null

[image]

but, when i export the same MovieClip by GAF tools, it's read the mask info perfectly

[image]

so, any clue how they did this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, I assume that "childMc" is the star object which is on the "Start" layer and you have another layer with the mask; and both layers are on the main timeline. Try moving the mask inside the "childMc" and see if you can get the mask info.

Comment: yes,childMc is the Start. and if move mask in Start may get the result, but not really what i want do :(, as i say ,i want build an tool like [GAF](http://gafmedia.com/converter/).so i try to support as mush as i can without bound any special rule.

Comment: You should check then all the children on stage and find the one that has a mask.

Comment: i traced all the child,none of them have mask property ,also if want know which child is Mask, that part is easy, the hard one is to know who masked who,currently all display object's mask propery is null(you can wrote an demo to test out),so any clue how GAF does the trigger?

Comment: GAF analyzes the bytecode of the swf, so it probably extracts the information differently than what you're trying. There was a bug in flash (still is, I guess) that doesn't let you access timeline masks [link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=797477)

Comment: Yes，that make sense. it seems i can't did what GAF do. shamed :( , anyway,thanks a lot!